# Prove that every manifold is regular.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that every manifold is regular and hence metrizable.

Comment: What are the definitions of "manifold" and "regular" you are working with?

Comment: I got a regular locally. This implies the regularity of the manifold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: A space $X$ is regular if and only for each point $x\in X$ and each open nbhd $U$ of $x$ there is an open set $V$ such that $x\in V\subseteq\operatorname{cl}V\subseteq U$. Use the fact that a manifold is locally Euclidean to prove that it has this property.

Comment: but I do not know if regular locally implies the regularity of the manifold?

Comment: @Jarbas: Regularity **is** a local property: look at that characterization at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: ok, but the neighborhood U is given, different from neighborhood  of the definition of manifold

Comment: @Jarbas: That doesn’t matter. Oh, you have to do a little work, but not much. Remember, the intersection of two open sets is open.

Comment: Let $x$ and $U$ so that $x \in U$, $X$ it is a manifold, then exist $V$ neigboord of $x$ so that $f(V)$ it is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where f it is a homeomorphism....ok?

Comment: @Jarbas: All of that is true and necessary, but you’ve not yet reached the main step. Let $W=U\cap V$; then $W$ is an open nbhd of $x$ in the regular space $V$, so ...

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ it is locally compact, then $f(V)$ it is Hausdorff and locally compact, this implies that $f(V)$ it is regular... ok?

Comment: @Jarbas: That’s okay, but even simpler is the fact that $\Bbb R^n$ is metrizable, so $V$ is metrizable, and every metric space is regular.

Comment: $V$ regular implies that for every $W$ open in $V$ neigboord of $x$ exist $W_0$ so that $x \in W_0 \subset cl W_0 \subset W $

Comment: @Jarbas: And therefore $\operatorname{cl}W_0\subseteq U$, which is what you really wanted to get.

Comment: @Jarbas: You’re welcome!

Comment: $W_0$ it is open in $X$ because $V$ it is open, and cl$W_0$ in $X$ is containd in $V$

Comment: @Jarbas: Yes, and yes.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The closure of $W_0$ in $V$ and $X$ are different, we have $\mathrm{cl}_V(W_0)=\mathrm{cl}_X(W_0)\cap V$. How can you say $\mathrm{cl}_X(W_0)\subset V$?

Answer (score 3):

Brian M. Scott has given very clear clue to follow, but one thing to notice as Xiang Yu has put forward, $clW_0$ is in fact the closed set in the $ U \bigcap V$ while we need a closed set in X to prove the regularity.

Hausdorff condition is necessary to prove the regularity in Munkrres' Topology.

refer to ["Error"/"Gap" in proof on every topological manifold being regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399035/error-gap-in-proof-on-every-topological-manifold-being-regular)